# Unity, add rotation on top of raycast . normal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to apply some rotation around the Y axis after I rotate a gameobject to match the terrain based on a raycast :

```
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hitInfo;

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 50, mask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
{
    //move object to point ( working )
    gm.transform.position = hitInfo.point;

    //apply rotation to mach the terrain ( working )
    gm.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normalized);

    //add some rotation ( float ) around the Y axis ( NOT working )
    gm.transform.rotation += Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotation, 0f);
}
```

For some reason when I disable last line applying more rotation everything is normal, when I enable it, x and z rotations are defaulted to something like 0.0317 or 0 and Y rotation isn't applied at all.

I really don't know what's wrong, pls help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `gm.transform.Rotate(0f, rotation, 0f, Space.World);`

Comment: Couldn't resolve the problem that I wanted, but I found an other way around it, first I get the child GameObject using `GameObject child = gm.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;` then apply Local Rotation to it.
                    `child.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotation, 0f);`
It kinda works, but still hoping someone answer the question above.

Comment: @Ruzihm tried your method, but didn't work, found later that when the game object is perpendicular on Z axis I need to rotate it around X axis, and when it's on X axis rotating around Z and Y axis acts in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ruzihm Helped saying

> try gm.transform.Rotate(0f, rotation, 0f, Space.World);

It didn't work, it was rotating around the Y axis in the world, It nedeed to be local, so by changing it to
`gm.transform.Rotate(0f, rotation, 0f, Space.Self);` it works perfectly, thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help. You can actually just do `gm.transform.Rotate(0f, rotation, 0f);` because `Space.Self` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

```
gm.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Angle, Vector3.up);
```

`Angle` should be in degrees.

Comment: @Ruzihm I've fixed the code to work with rotation instead of direction vectors my bad.
What do you mean it won't compile? What errors does it give

Comment: Well it is already in degrees, rotation variable is beteen 0 and 360